# Sharepoint Hosted app update issue

Tags: list, upgrade, site, sharepoint-hosted-app, schema

I have deployed my hosted app in test site environment with version 2.0.0.0 In the same version I have one list named **Employee**. Now I renamed the list name as **Employees** raise the version 3.0.0.0 and updated the app in same test site environment. 
The issue now I am facing is that in updated app there are two lists present named **Employee** and **Employees**. I don't understand why this is happening. Suggest some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your App/Addin upgrade won't wipe out any app web content, that's reason why you still see the Employee list. You might need to retract the app and install again if you want a fresh start on app web contents.

Comment: This solution is not workable in live environment (Client Context) where you already have data in the lists